# Update specific row in FOREACH loop

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql

I've tried and tried, but I can't get this to work. I use Joomla and I have 2 articles/pages, one for edit and one for posting the form. I have a database with all the matches for the World Cup coming up and I want my users to bet on the matches.

I have 2 tables - one with all matches like this (named `vm_kampe`):

```
|id |hhold   |uhold   |res  |
|1  |Rusland |Saudi   |NULL |
|2  |Egypten |Uruguay |NULL |
... and so on
```

and the other table is my coupon where my bets are stored(named `vm_207` where 207 is my user-id, so every user gets its own table):

```
|id |resu |
|1  |2-1  |
|2  |1-3  |
... and so on.
```

So the id in `vm_207` should connect to the id of the match in `vm_kampe`.

So I want a page, where I can update my bets, so I have this:

```
foreach($results as $row){     
echo '<div class="vm_kupon_row">     
<div class="vm_id"><input type="hidden" name="kampid[]" value="'.$row->id.'"></div>     
<div class="vm_kampe">'.$row->hhold.' - '.$row->uhold.'</div>     
<div class="vm_result"><input class="vm_resultat" type="text" name="resultat[]" placeholder="X-X" value="'.$row->resu.'"></div>

</div>';

};

echo '<input type="submit" class="godkend-vm-kupon" name="submit" value="Godkend">';
```

That calls out all matches with an input field where the value is selected from my table `vm_207` and it works. Now, if I change something I want to update, the form action calls this page:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$kampid = $jinput->get('$kampid');
$resultat = $jinput->get('$resultat', 'string');

$fields = array(
$db->quoteName('resu') . ' = ' . $db->quote($resultat)
);

$conditions = array(
$db->quoteName('id') . '=' . $kampid
);

$query->update($db->quoteName('vm_207'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);
```

But it won't update anything.

Please help me make this work. If you need any more details just say so :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post links to code, include it in your question as text formatted as code. Make it easy for people to help you, few people will bother to follow a link to help you out.

Comment: Also, edit your question to show the schema of the tables involved.

Comment: @SloanThrasher So, I editted my question :)

Comment: In the 2nd page, you'll need to step through each of the values to build up your update queries, and execute the query once per row of the original table. You can't do it just once. You might try echoing the values passed to the page so you can see what the data looks like.

Comment: I would just like to say that generating a new table for each user seems like poor architecture.  Why wouldn't you just create a single table and dedicate a column for the users' ids?  This way you can write simple join queries.  If there is a compelling reason to create a bunch of identically structured tables, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa :) You're right - it was bad architecture. I ended up with a single table as you suggested :) I just forgot about this post again afterwards. But I now have one table containing all users bets :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are missing the following lines (which effectively execute the update operation):

```
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->execute();
```

Can you check?

Comment: Wow, I didn't execute the operation :D Jesus ... Thank you :)